# Centrino Advanced-N 6230 and bluetooth wireless problems with Dell XPS 15z

Tags: 11.10, wireless, dell, bluetooth, xps

I've been have a lot of problems with getting my wireless to work reliably on my Dell XPS 15z. There's a lot of talk about this on [other](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19382502.aspx) [forums](http://forum.notebookreview.com/dell-xps-studio-xps/602663-dell-xps-15z-wireless-issues.html), and it appears to have something to do with the Bluetooth interfering with the Wireless.

So, to explain where I'm at: I can get connected for about 15 minutes before it disconnects and won't connect again. Selecting my network from the list just makes it sit there for a while before it asks me for the password *again*.

The other thing which is very strange and VERY annoying is that if I disable Bluetooth via the gnome panel ( `B` -> Disable Bluetooth), it turns off **both** the bluetooth **and** the wireless, and THEN I can't turn it back on because it claims that "wireless is disabled by hardware switch", and the same for the Bluetooth. Even restarting from here doesn't help. The actual hardware switch (<kbd>fn + F2</kbd>) does nothing at all, unless I boot into Windows, which is obviously less than satisfactory.

So! I don't use any Bluetooth devices at all, so perhaps if I *actually* disable it, then the wireless might come back. But I don't know how to do that...

Any help or advice?

---

Debugging information:

```
$ sudo lspci -nn

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0126] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1c18] (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:1c1a] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c4b] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation Device [10de:0df5] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [8086:0091] (rev 34)
04:00.0 USB Controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 04)
05:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller [197b:2392] (rev 30)
05:00.2 SD Host controller [0805]: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller [197b:2391] (rev 30)
05:00.3 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller [197b:2393] (rev 30)
05:00.4 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller [197b:2394] (rev 30)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
```

```
$ sudo lshw -class network

  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6230
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 34
       serial: 88:53:2e:37:d8:45
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic firmware=17.168.5.1 build 33993 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:19 memory:f1b00000-f1b01fff
```

*I removed the ethernet eth0 information for brevity*

```
$ iwconfig

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

```
$ rfkill list

0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Added note: after booting to Windows and re-enabling the wireless with the hotkey, then restarting in Ubuntu again, the `rfkill` output says `'no'` to all options, and it connects happily to network. `iwconfig` now looks like this:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"kokomo"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: E0:46:9A:09:94:D0   
          Bit Rate=2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:38   Missed beacon:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a pretty similare issue. But when i try <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd> it enable the wireless card, bluetooth,...
On your rfkill list, the cards are hard blocked, so it's not a software issue i think.

If you try to strike <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd> it does nothing ?

When my bluetooth is disabled, i can connect to a wifi connection without beeing disconnected for a while but i have to not use the bluetooth and it is petty annoying...

Did you find a solution ? Or do you know new things about this issue ?

Comment: no clue -- i actually traded it in for a thinkpad in the end. :-

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and here is the voodoo dance that tends to resolve the problem:

```
# rmmod iwlagn
# modprobe iwlagn 11n_disable=1 power_level=5

## no comes the fun part: 
## enable and disable your wireless with Fn + F2 (on my maching)
```

Sometimes it helps to `rmmod btusb bluetooth` but I haven't figured that out yet.

I have only tested this on ArchLinux with kernel 3.1.4.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I couldn't turn on wifi or bluetooth after disabling bluetooth, or wifi after disabling wifi, and that fn+f2 had no effect in ubuntu. With the help of the person above, and some other forums, this fixed the problem:

```
sudo modprobe iwlagn power_level=5
sudo modprobe btusb reset=1
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

After that, fn+f2 works, bluetooth can be disabled without disabling wifi, and wifi can be re-enabled after it is disabled.